# VueJS and antdesign vue - Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-import' from

Tags: vue.js, ant-design-pro, babel-plugin

I came across a problem installing vueJS with ant-design and after reboot of serve it gave below error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-import' from xxx`

My steps were:

1. Install vueJS project via `vue ui`
2. Install dependencies for ant-design via `vue ui`
3. Rerun the server

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the `ant-design` install does overwrite some `babel-import-plugin` values.

I could resolve it by install of `babel-import-plugin` again after I did the install of `ant-design`.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Sad to see your question got downvoted. How did you install the 'babel-import-plugin' ? npm/yarn, or vue ui? Did you encounter more environment related problems with ant-design?